# Iterate elements of pandas column over elements of another column from a different data frame of unequal length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, bioinformatics

I have two Pandas data frames of unequal length, the first one contains data about predicted protein modifications, the second one holds data for experimentally verified protein modifications

The first data frame contains the following columns:

- protein_id
- position_predicted
- modification_predicted

… and looks something like this:

| protein_id | position_predicted | modification_predicted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| prot1 | 135 | + |
| prot1 | 267 | + |
| prot1 | 360 | - |
| prot2 | 59 | ++ |
| prot2 | 135 | +++ |
| prot3 | 308 | - |
| … | … | … |

The second data frame contains columns with experimentally verified protein modification positions:

- protein_id
- position_experimental

… and looks like so:

| protein_id | position |
| --- | --- |
| prot1 | 135 |
| prot3 | 300 |
| prot4 | 55 |
| … | … |

**protein_id** in both columns refers to the same protein, using standard Uniprot identifier

**modification_predicted** in the first data frame responds to information about the predicted presence of the modification on the position:
‘+’ modification predicted to be present
‘-’ modification predicted to be absent
On the contrary, the second data frame holds the position are experimentally (truly) present

Now my global aim is to somehow compare the accuracy of the predictions from data frame one with the experimentally verified modifications from data frame two.

There are 5 cases that I have to count separately:

- A) experimental data frame and predictions data frame both have same position for same protein and the prediction says the position is truly modified (‘+’ in the **modification_predicted**) - *true positive* cases
- B) position in both data frames is same, but the same prediction says there’s no modification (‘-‘ in the **modification_predicted**) for the same corresponding protein - *false negative* cases
- C) prediction says there’s a modification for the position (‘+’ in the **modification_predicted**), but the experimental data frame has no corresponding position for this same protein - *false positive* cases
- D) prediction says there’s no modification for the position (‘-’ in the **modification_predicted**) and the experimental data frame has no corresponding position for this same protein - *true negative* cases
- E) the experimental data frame positions that do not correspond to any position for the same protein in the prediction data frame - *miscellanaous*

Now I understand that I need to somewhere iterate over each position of each protein in the prediction data frame over each position for each corresponding protein in the experimental data frame

In pseudo-code the way I see the solution for this problem is something like this

```
TP = 0
FN = 0
TN = 0
FP = 0
Misc = 0

for protein in df1$protein_id:
   for position in protein[from df1]:
      if {condition for TP}:
         TP += 1
      if {condition for FN}:
         FN += 1
      if {condition for TN}:
         TN += 1
      if (condition for FP):
         FP += 1
      if {condition for misc}:
         Misc += 1
```

There are two major problems that I face with such a solution.

(1) How do I specify for each condition that I need to compare only same protein positions positions between the two frames, in other words restrict the comparison only to within-single-protein positions, without allowing for inter-protein comparisons
(2) The length of the two frames is unequal

Any ideas how to approach these problems?

Comment: why are there several pluses? `++` and `+++`. Should they all count as `+` ?

Comment: @VladimirFokow depends on the strength of the prediction, but initially I planned to count all of them as just one plus, i.e. modification present

Answer (score 0):

You can use merging. Reference: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

> I assume the index numbers (of both dataframes) are unique. If not, use: `df.reset_index()`

```py
# Inner merge:
intersection = df_pred.merge(
    df_real, 
    left_on=['protein_id', 'position_predicted'], 
    right_on=['protein_id', 'position']
)

TP = intersection['modification_predicted'].str.contains('+', regex=False).sum()
FN = intersection['modification_predicted'].eq('-').sum()
# FN = len(intersection) - TP  # alternative
```

And here select elements of both dataframes which are **not** present in the other one:

```py
unique_pred = df_pred.loc[df_pred.index.difference(intersection.index)]
unique_real = df_real.loc[df_real.index.difference(intersection.index)]
```

```py
TN = unique_pred['modification_predicted'].eq('-').sum()
FP = unique_pred['modification_predicted'].str.contains('+', regex=False).sum()
# FP = len(unique_pred) - TN  # alternative

Misc = len(unique_real)
```

**Result:**

```py
>>> TP, FN, TN, FP, Misc
(1, 0, 2, 3, 2)
```